# Parsing href to capture parts of it

Tags: java

```
 <ContentFragment><![CDATA[<a target=_blank href=$click_tracking_url$&landing_url=https://www.foo.com><img src='urltoimage.jpg' border='0' alt='' /></a>]]></ContentFragment>
```

I have this xml segment of a file which i have access to ContentFragment via JAXB. and ContentFragment is a string.

I want to find out how can i capture if the a href is targeted for new window as well as if a click tracking url is there or not.

As far as what i have done, I can do a `string.contains("_blank");` or `string.contains("click_tracking_url");` then i can parse.

is there a better way to do it such as parsing a href into parts?

Comment: You could actually parse it via HTML/XML parser and access the attributes, but is that really necessary? What doesn't work with how you're doing it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are great Java libraries for parsing XML...

... and there are great Java libraries for parsing HTML ...

... but for simply parsing out an "href" inside an `<a>` tag inside `[CDATA]` element:

`String.contains()` and `String.indexOf()` should be more than sufficient.

IMHO...

Comment: yeah i guess i ll stick with string methods, rather than bringing a new jar etc to the project just for this. thanks.